# day.js is not converting UTC to local time

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, utc, dayjs

I am running into an issue trying to convert **momentjs** over to **day.js**.

In moment, I converted utc to local time via `moment.utc('2020-04-22T14:56:09.388842').local().format('MM/DD/YY h:mm A')` which returns `04/22/20 9:56 AM`.

When I convert with **day.js** via `dayjs.utc('2020-04-22T14:56:09.388842').local().format('MM/DD/YY h:mm A')`, I get `04/22/20 2:56 PM`; I am importing the utc plugin.

I put an example in jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/obdg74sp/2/

Has anyone ran into this issue and if you did, how did you resolve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both Moment and Day.js only support millisecond precision, however they differ in behavior when more than 3 decimals are passed in for parsing.

- Moment will ignore the extra decimals, but will still use its own parsing logic
- Day.js reverts to the `Date.parse` function

In the latter case, there is no UTC awareness, so you get local time, despite being passed through the `dayjs.utc` function.

This was brought up in [Day.js issue #544](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/544), and closed by the owner of that library without any change.

You can work around this by trimming the string to truncate the extra decimals.

```
dayjs.utc('2020-04-22T14:56:09.388842'.substring(0, 23))
```

Then it will parse UTC correctly, and the rest of your logic will work accordingly.

(Alternatively, you could append a `Z` to the string)

Answer (score 11):

I used:

`dayjs(date).utc('z').local().tz(ianaCode).format('ddd, MMM D, H:mm z')`

Example:

`dayjs('2021-06-08T24:00:00').utc('z').local().tz('America/Detroit').format('ddd, MMM D, H:mm z')`